# How to deploy Google app engine application through the deployment manager ? Is it possible to do it

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am deploying all my application to Appengine. I found a "Development" tool in the Developer Console and configured it to sync my Appengine project files. I utilized the online editing feature to edit an appengine project file through the Development tool. I made changes and committed the code.
So I want to know whether it is possible to use deployment manager for deploying the app engine services??

Can someone help me on how I can use the Deployment Manager to deploy the changes I made online? I went through the Deployment Manager documentation online but it doesn't speak of how to deploy a Appengine project using Deployment manager.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.

The generic steps to make a deployment using Deployment Manager (DM) are listed in the [Step-by-step walkthrough guide](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/). The most important ones are:

- [Installation and Setup](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/installation-and-setup)
- [Creating a Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/create-a-configuration).
- [Deploying Your Resources](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/deploy-your-resources)

See also [Deployment Manager Fundamentals](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/fundamentals).

What may be confusing is how to do it specifically for GAE. Well, 
that's entirely reflected in the content of your config file, more specifically in the [resource type](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) - the GAE's [Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/) is used, see the  [`appengine.v1.version`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions) row in the table.

But the DM appears oriented more towards manual deployments. From your question I suspect you *might* be interested more into automatically deploying your changes once committed. If so you you may want to peek at [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/) and [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/) instead. See [Quickstart for automating App Engine deployments with Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart-triggering-builds-with-source-repositories).